# The product page moves down - Magento 2

Tags: product, attributes, page

Good morning,
I have a problem ... clean installation plus sample products. When you do not choose attributes and press button add to cart, the page is going down. Why is this happening?

https://demo-magento-2.auroracreation.com/pl/argus-all-weather-tank.html

Answer (score 2):

can you please check your Magento version because this is the default Magento bug in Magento version 2.3.1 and 2.3.2 and might be for other versions too

Comment: Magento ver. 2.3.1 Is it possible to fix it somehow?

Comment: you can fix it by applying custom js to prevent scroll